# Image does not load

Tags: 7, theming

I bought a theme from themebrain site and installed it. Some of the images for the theme are stored inside /sites/default/files/customs/. So in image tags, I refer to the source location as "sites/default/files/customs/xxx.png". However, those image are not loading. I changed the directory permission recursively to 777, but that does not resolve the issue either. But images inside  /sites/all/themes/tb_travel/ load just fine though. If anyone could guide me to right direction, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: It sounds strange that theme files would be stored outside of /sites/all/themes/mytheme/ or /sites/default/themes/mytheme/

Comment: Do you get a 403 or a 404 error when you load the image direectly?  http://example.com/sites/default/files/customs/xxx.png  That would identify if it's a file location issue or a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the image tags have an absolute path "/sites/default/files/customs/xxx.png" and not relative, "sites/default/files/customs/xxx.png".  I've palm-to-faced many times because of that.

For example:"/node/123/sites/default/files/customs/palm-to-face.png" won't load!

Comment: It was a typos in my directory name. Silly mistake. But I marked your answer as correct, as I have made such mistake in the past and got my time wasted. Thanks very much for your time.